# Prove that if for a number x ∈ R x + x ^(-1) ∈ Z ..... I can't get started it would be very important. please

Tags: integers

** Prove that if for a number x ∈ R    x + x ^(-1) ∈ Z ,  then for all n ∈ Z cases x^n + x^(−n) ∈ Z.**strong text****

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Are you sure that is true? $$4 \in \mathbb{R}, 4^1+4^{-1}=\frac{17}{4} \not \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: You need to prove this using some form of induction.

Comment: @Khosrotash
  ohh it's still hard to understand

Comment: @player3236 too it's still hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

If $x + \frac{1}{x} = a$, then solve for $x$ in terms of $a$.

Then, prove the following lemma:

If $a$ is an integer and $b,n$ are a positive integers, then

$$(a + \sqrt{b})^n + (a - \sqrt{b})^n ~\text{is an integer}.$$

**Hint-2**

$$\left[a \times \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4}}{2}\right] ~-~ 1 ~=~ \left[\frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4}}{2}\right]^2.$$

Comment: can i ask for a little more information? :)))

Comment: can i ask for a little more information?

Comment: @tom2563 Just providing you with these hints **approached** violating mathSE protocol.  To say more would cross the boundary.  See these links:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933.  Your query has already received two down votes because it did not meet the mathSE standard discussed in these links.  You need to edit your query in accordance with these links.

Comment: ohh, im so sorry, im a beginner :((

Comment: so solve for x with a its ready. and after? 
please help a little more

Comment: @tom2563 You have to edit your query to show that you have made a legitimate attempt to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$, discover the relationship between the problem and the lemma, and then prove the lemma.  You do **not** have to succeed.  But you do have to edit your query to show a serious attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Induction hint: The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are trivial.

Suppose $x^{n-1} + x^{1-n}$ and $x^{n-2} + x^{2-n}$ are integers.

Consider the product $(x + x^{-1})(x^{n-1} + x^{1-n})$, and show that $x^n + x^{-n}$ must be an integer.

Comment: +1 : After finding a kludgy solution associated with my first hint, I found a more elegant Fibonacci-like approach associated with my 2nd hint.  Your approach is even more elegant.